# R: Syntax problems in averaging columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset with NDVI data and forest type My NDVI columns are full of NaN's. I am trying to average 2 NDVI columns (vegetation index from 0-1) and then compute the mean by forest type. My approach would be to create a third column and then compute average. Something like:

```
  data_full %>%
  mutate(sum = sum(meanNDVIyear11,meanNDVIyear12, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(sum = sum/2) %>% 
  group_by(OriginalForest) %>% 
  summarise(meanNDVI = mean(sum,na.rm=TRUE))

  The output is  simply wrong:
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  OriginalForest meanNDVI
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 bushland           292.
2 Conifer            292.
3 Decidious          292.
4 Sclerofilous       292.
```

Instead in a very nasty way I can also do:

```
data_full %>%
group_by(OriginalForest) %>%
summarise(meanNDVI = mean(((meanNDVIyear12+meanNDVIyear11)/2),na.rm=TRUE))
```

And it works!

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  OriginalForest meanNDVI
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 bushland          0.462
2 Conifer           0.533
3 Decidious         0.479
4 Sclerofilous      0.557
```

I am so curios to know what I am doing wrong in the first approach, which is clearly more elegant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first approach, it is taking the `sum` of the entire two column and thus the `mean` is the same as `sum` take multiple arguments and get the sum of all of them

```
data(mtcars)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    mutate(sum = sum(mpg, cyl))

#                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   sum
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 840.9
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 840.9
#Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 840.9
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 840.9
#...
```

i.e.

```
with(mtcars, sum(mpg) + sum(cyl))
#[1] 840.9
```